# What does the ‘ovs-dpctl show’ command means?

Tags: openvswitch

When I execute the 'ovs-dpctl show' command, I got:

```
$ ovs-dpctl show
system@ovs-system:
    lookups: hit:37994604 missed:218759 lost:0
    flows: 5
    masks: hit:39862430 total:5 hit/pkt:1.04
    port 0: ovs-system (internal)
    port 1: vbr0 (internal)
    port 2: gre_sys (gre)
    port 3: net2
```

I retrieved some explanations:

```
[-s | --statistics] show [dp...]
              Prints a summary of configured datapaths, including their  data‐
              path  numbers  and  a  list of ports connected to each datapath.
              (The local port is identified as port 0.)  If -s or --statistics
              is specified, then packet and byte counters are also printed for
              each port.

              The datapath numbers consists of flow stats and mega  flow  mask
              stats.

              The  "lookups"  row  displays three stats related to flow lookup
              triggered by processing incoming packets in the datapath.  "hit"
              displays number of packets matches existing flows. "missed" dis‐
              plays the number of packets not matching any existing  flow  and
              require  user space processing.  "lost" displays number of pack‐
              ets destined for user space process but subsequently dropped be‐
              fore  reaching  userspace. The sum of "hit" and "miss" equals to
              the total number of packets datapath processed.

              The "flows" row displays the number of flows in datapath.

              The "masks" row displays the mega flow mask stats. This  row  is
              omitted  for datapath not implementing mega flow. "hit" displays
              the total number of masks visited for matching incoming packets.
              "total" displays number of masks in the datapath. "hit/pkt" dis‐
              plays the average number of masks visited per packet; the  ratio
              between "hit" and total number of packets processed by the data‐
              path.

              If one or more datapaths  are  specified,  information  on  only
              those  datapaths  are  displayed.  Otherwise, ovs-dpctl displays
              information about all configured datapaths.
```

my question is:

1. Is the total number of incoming packets equal to (lookups.hit +
   lookups.missed)?
2. If the total number of incoming packets is equal to
   (lookups.hit + lookups.missed), why is the value of masks.hit:39862430 
   greater than (lookups.hit:37994604 + lookups.missed:218759)?
3. Why is the masks.hit/pkt ratio greater than 1? What is the reasonable 
   value in what interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is the total number of incoming packets equal to (lookups.hit +
>      lookups.missed)?

Yes.  (Plus lookups.lost except that I see that's zero for you.)

> 2. If the total number of incoming packets is equal to
>      (lookups.hit + lookups.missed), why is the value of masks.hit:39862430
>      greater than (lookups.hit:37994604 + lookups.missed:218759)?

masks.hit is the number of hash table lookups that were executed to
process all of the packets that were processed.  A given packet might
require up to masks.total lookups.

> 3. Why is the masks.hit/pkt ratio greater than 1? What is the reasonable
>      value in what interval?

The ratio cannot be less than 1.00 because that would mean that
processing a packet didn't require even a single lookup.  A ratio of
1.04 is very good because it means that most packets were processed with
only a single lookup.  Higher ratios are worse.

by Ben Pfaff (blp@ovn.org)